# .net framework architecture for 32-bit app running on 64-bit os

Tags: .net

What is the .net framework architecture for a 32-bit application running on 64-bit OS?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if your application is set to run 32-bit, it will use a 32-bit version of the framework even on 64-bit Windows.

Before your edit, you said you knew the location of the running clr. You can then also tell the difference in that the corresponding 64-bit version of the clr.dll would be located in **Framework64**.

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll

Answer (score 1):

32-bit .Net applications run on 32-bit .Net.

64-bit .Net applications run on 64-bit .Net.

Comment: @MattWilko: No; it should not.